# How Remove and purge lam mpi from ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, mpi, ubuntu-18.04, purge

I recently tried to uninstall `lam mpi` on **Ubuntu 18.04** to replace it with  **open MPI**.

I ran the following command:

```
 sudo apt install lam4-dev
```

It did not work, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

So after searches and searches i finally found one way to do this.

So lets do this. Its really simple.

just run this code on your terminal.

```
 sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove lam4-dev
```

Again i am using the **ubuntu 18-04**

i hope this post help you out. If not tell perhaps i forgot something.

for some reason i had installed the openmpi-bin package

so i runned this other command

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove openmpi-bin

sudo apt-get purge openmpi-bin
```

again i hope this help you out